# CMake strange behavior

Tags: makefile, cmake, mingw, msys

After I generated Makefile with CMake I ran in MSYS:

```
msys>make
```

It launched cmd.exe within msys and started new make.exe process that did nothing.
It's not a single case - every project that I try to build with CMake leads to this trap.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSYS and MinGW makefiles (as CMake understands it) is not the same. In this case I used to generate MSYS makefiles.

Comment: MinGW is not MSYS, even outside of CMake context. Just build CMake projects outside of MSYS. It'll go faster too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use MinGW compiler, I suggest you use MinGW shell prompt instead of MS cmd.exe. This ensure that several MinGW compiler specific environment variables are correctly set.

Then use **"MinGW Makefiles"** as generator and `mingw32-make` as make program.

If you use MSYS you must use **"MSYS Makefiles"** and the make program should be called simply `make` (if you have installed it correctly).

If you generate "MinGW Makefiles" and call `make`, the wrong make program is called. Specify explicitely `mingw32-make`.